# I am using unittest.TestCase if i have more than 1 test case it will not run. Only 1 test case runs

Tags: python, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

I am automating our website. I am using Python, Webdriver, `unittest.TestCase`.

I had 1 test method defined in my Login Page class which is to test a valid user log in. That works fine.

Now i am adding a 2nd test method called test_login_invalid_user to test an invalid user log in. I am just browsing to the log in page to start with to see if the 2nd test method gets called when i run my test.

When i run my code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore  \LoginPage_TestCase.py", line 40, in test_login_invalid_user
login_page = page.login(self.driver)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'login'
```

Can I not have more than 1 test method in my unit test?
I am doing it the wrong way?

My unit test class code snippet is as follows:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import page
import time

class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium  Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")

    def test_login_valid_user(self):
        login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        login_page.isAdministration_present()
        assert login_page.isAdministration_present(), "Administration not found"
        if login_page.isAdministration_present() == "true":
            print "test login with a valid user passed"
        else:
            print "test login with a valid user failed"

    def test_login_invalid_user(self):
        print "test_login_invalid_user"
        login_page = page.login(self.driver)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you meant to define a new `LoginPage` page object instance instead:

```
def test_login_invalid_user(self):
    print "test_login_invalid_user"
    login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
```

If this is the case, to avoid violating the "DRY" principle and to improve readability, instantiate `LoginPage` in `setUp()`:

```
class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium  Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")

        self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)

    def test_login_valid_user(self):
        self.login_page.userLogin_valid()
        self.login_page.isAdministration_present()
        assert self.login_page.isAdministration_present(), "Administration not found"
        if self.login_page.isAdministration_present() == "true":
            print "test login with a valid user passed"
        else:
            print "test login with a valid user failed"

    def test_login_invalid_user(self):
        print "test_login_invalid_user"
        # use self.login_page here
```